# Proper way to return array data in multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, post, multidimensional-array

What is the proper way to grab all data from an array in a multidimensional array?

```
Array
(
[0]Array
    (
        [0] Array
            (
                [day] 3/1/2016
                [start1] 12:15am
                [end1] 1:15am
                [start2] 
                [end2] 
            )

        [1] Array
            (
                [day] 3/2/2016
                [start1] 12:00am
                [end1] 1:00am
                [start2] 
                [end2] 
            )

        [2] Array
            (
                [day] 3/3/2016
                [start1] 12:00am
                [end1] 12:00am
                [start2] 
                [end2] 
            )

    )

)
```

I would like to loop through and grab all the information for each nested array  but I seem to be running into an undefined index error.

```
foreach($timeArray as $day){
echo "Day: " + $day['day'] + "Start1: " + $day['start1'] + "End1: " + $day['end1'] + "Start2: " + $day['start2'] +"End2: " + $day['end2'];
}
```

Comment: sorry I am getting my js and php mixed up now. need sleep lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$timeArray` is the complete array, then

- `$timeArray[0]` is the array beneath it, which has all the days
- `$timeArray[0][0]` is the first element of the array beneath it, which is the first day
- `$timeArray[0][0]["day"]` contains the value `3/1/2016`

---

Another note would be that you are concatenating your strings incorrectly:

- `"Text " + $variable + " Text"` = wrong
- `"Text $variable Text"` = right
- `"Text {$variable["key"]} Text"` = also right

---

So to access each day:

```
foreach($timeArray[0] as $day){
    echo "Day: {$day['day']}",
         "Start1: {$day['start1']}",
         "End1: {$day['end1']}",
         "Start2: {$day['start2']}",
         "End2: {$day['end2']}";
}
```

---

*Reference:*

- *[PHP: String Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)*
- *[PHP: Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)*

Comment: thank you for the explanation and the references.  definitely helped clear things up for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you array has 2 levels, assuming your example is the whole content of your array this would work

Also the concatenation character in PHP is `.` and not `+`

```
foreach($timeArray[0] as $day){
    echo "Day: " . $day['day'] . 
         "Start1: " . $day['start1'] . 
         "End1: " . $day['end1'] . 
         "Start2: " . $day['start2'] . 
         "End2: " . $day['end2'];
}
```

You could also make use of the fact the a double quoted string will expand variable like this

```
foreach($timeArray[0] as $day){
    echo "Day: {$day['day']} Start1: {$day['start1']} End1: {$day['end1']} ";
    echo "Start2: {$day['start2']} End2: {$day['end2']}";
}
```

Or if you dont quote the array names

```
foreach($timeArray[0] as $day){
    echo "Day: $day[day] Start1: $day[start1] End1: $day[end1] ";
    echo "Start2: $day[start2]} End2: $day[end2]";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can read your array by this:

```
foreach ($your_arr as $key_internal=>$arr_internal){
        foreach ($arr_internal as $key=>$value){
             echo $value['day'];
             ......
        }
}
```